# Javascript - Each letter of an input to an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an input type text with maxlength=5, like this:

```
<input id="word" type="text" name="word" maxlength="5">
<button id="btn"> Send </button>
```

Is there any way to receive the input and separate each of the letters to each index of an array?

Example:

```
input= "carro";
array=["c","a","r","r","o"]
```

I know how to put the input in the array but not separated like this.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: what did you try? can you show us some code please?

Comment: `array = [...string]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are usualy more than one way to do something in JS.
I know 3 ways to get an array from a string.

1. Use `.split` with blank string as an argument.
   But, as @georg mentioned, "it doesn't work with 32-bit characters, e.g. emojis".
2. Use method [.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) of `Array` object.
3. Or newest way: another method [.of](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of) in combination with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```html
<input id="word" type="text" name="word" maxlength="5" value="carro">
<button id="btn"> Send </button>
<script>
  document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    const value = document.querySelector('#word').value

    // const array = value.split('')
    // const array = Array.from(value)
    const array = Array.of(...value)
    console.log(array)
  })
</script>
```

Comment: The problem with `split('')` is that it doesn't work with 32-bit characters, e.g. emojis

Answer (score 1):

`split` method will be useful to fix your issue

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(){
    var input =document.getElementById('word').value;
    var val = input.split('');
    console.log(val);
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='word' value='carro'>
<button id='btn'>Send</button>
```